# Data migration in LDAP

Tags: ldap, data-migration, sun, ldif

What is the best way to load data in LDAP where the data count is 10 million, tried with LDIF file which took more than 40 min for 300k records. Looking for an option to load 10 million records in less than 5 hrs. Is there anything that can be done to load data faster in LDAP

Comment: try bulkload if it's available.

Comment: Which LDAP product? If it's OpenLDAP you should use `slapadd` with the server in offline mode, rather than `ldapadd`. I'm sure it's quicker than 40m/300k.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response on this, it's Sun LDAP

Comment: In that case you should investigate the utilities it comes with. Reading LDIF and feeding it via an LDAP client over a network isn't as fast as you probably need. The reason `slapadd` is fast is because it operates directly on the database.